# Are there any common tourist traps in New York City?

Tags: usa, new-york-city, tourist-traps

For example, are there cabs one should avoid?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? A [tourist trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_trap) is "an establishment that has been created or re-purposed with the aim of attracting tourists and their money." and there are thousands in NY. In any case if you mean scams asking for a list of possible scams is going to be too long a list for this site and this question will probably be closed as not having a definite answer.

Comment: As written this is impossible to answer: it's at once too broad and too opinion-based. For example, I would argue that the observation deck of the Empire State Building is a tourist trap, others would disagree and say it is an iconic part of the visitor experience. Please edit the post to define more precisely what you are looking to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t take a picture with Mickey Mouse and his friends on Times Square, if you don’t want to give them money.

Comment: As it is not ethical?

Comment: @Iman No, because they’ll want payment for having their picture taken